# After jquery.ajax job finishes I want the loader to be hidden;how?

Tags: jquery

My aim is:

1. Press button in cshtml page
   2.After press the action goes to angular function.
   3.In the angular function i send some data to mvc controller function
2. The function creates excell with some info.
3. While the process is continuing a loader gif is apperaing on screen that tells the user loading data.

Everything is working up to now.
I want to loader.gif hide when the excel is created in the controller. I think this way: when creating the excel from controller,in cshtml the process should be done and in qjuery.ajax function, this action should be known  to hide the loader.gif. But how? how can i do that? Can anyone help me please?

my angular function is on the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in cshtml

```
 <div id="LoadingDiv"></div>
```

Before execution of Ajax function

```
$('#LoadingDiv').html('');
$('#LoadingDiv').fadeTo('slow', 0.8);
$('#LoadingDiv').append('<div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/loader.gif")"/></div>');
```

In Success and error Function of ajax

```
$('#LoadingDiv').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks,but this solution did not help me. I tried it.

Comment: Is there any error in console?? am using this in jquery and it is working.

Comment: No, no error on console. I looked to the place that the excel saved. excel is created and filled correctly. But the loader.gif still runs on my screen that gives me the thinking that the process is still running and the it is not finished to create the excel with desired info.

Comment: Please check the 2nd answer posted.

Comment: it worked thanks. However, when i publis my project to server and wanted to get the excel. The loader hide earlier than the excel created. How can i achieve this problem. Is this problem about the slow, 0.8 –

Comment: I checked again. The code works fine in local computer on localhost. But when i publish it. İt doesn't. Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: write this $('#LoadingDiv').fadeOut('slow'); after creation of excel in success function

Comment: success: function (result) {
                                $('#loaderDiv').fadeOut('slow');
                            },

Comment: I tried a lot of things. They all work in local computer. When ı publish the code to the server. It fails. I looked behind and ı see (502 bad gateway ) error. Since the excel took between 10-15 minutes to fil. I think it goes to timeout error. the excel file has more than 3200 rows and each row includes adress money values etc. etc. I got these values from mycrosoft crm2015 with fetchxml with link entities in controller. It takes too long ,becaouse of this the operation gives me the 502 error. the ajax code seems the code that you send.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are doing the same??

```
$('#loaderDiv').html('');
$('#loaderDiv').fadeTo('slow', 0.8);
$('#loaderDiv').append('<div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/loader.gif")"/></div>');

$.ajax({
url: '',
type: "POST",
data: data,
success: function (result) {
$('#loaderDiv').fadeOut('slow');                           
},
error: function () {
$('#loaderDiv').fadeOut('slow');            
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks. However, when i publis my project to server and wanted to get the excel. The loader hide earlier than the excel created. How can i achieve this problem. Is this problem about the slow, 0.8

Comment: I checked again. The code works fine in local computer on localhost. But when i publish it. İt doesn't. Can you help me about this problem?